# Java binary file (.raw) output

Tags: java, file-io, binaryfiles, paraview

How can I write .raw files in Java? I have to use this output file as a source file for ParaView.

Comment: [Java Tutorial on I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: I did go through the tutorial but I could my find the answer to my basic question i.e. How do I output data in .raw format. Can you please explain this to me.

Comment: Output to where? Standard Output? A file?

Comment: Basically I am trying to output data to a .raw file. I believe that this is a binary file format.

Comment: You need to know what the format is first. (Its not a Java standard format so no Java documentation will help you there) Once you know the format you can workout how to produce this in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike other binary file formats, `RAW` is camera specific: Each digital camera uses its own file format. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format

To read/write images in this format, you can use [Jrawio](http://jrawio.rawdarkroom.org/)